# Changing the default Eshell Directory

Tags: shell, emacs, eshell

Since I've started using git to manage my .emacs file, I've found it useful to keep everything in my ~/.emacs.d direcory.  I would like to have eshell, therefore, read ~/.emacs/eshell.el on startup instead of the default 
~/.eshell .

I thought this would be simple enough, just change the eshell-directory-name variable to point where I want:

```
(setq eshell-directory-name '("~/.emacs.d/eshell"))
```

However, when I do that, I get the error:

```
call-interactively: Autoloading failed to define function eshell
```

and eshell fails to load.

What is the correct way to change this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out:  the error message had nothing to do with the line in the config file, but everything to do with the *name* of the config file instead.

I separated out all of my custom eshell configurations into a file called eshell.el  This made emacs skip the eshel.elc from my instillation on startup, because emacs looks in the user's custom directory first and uses the file that is there instead if it has the same name.   So changing the filename to my_ehsell.el magically fixed this problem.

As to the proper way to define that variable, that is best answered in this question:
[Difference between `set`, `setq`, and `setf` in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869529/difference-between-set-setq-and-setf-in-common-lisp)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
M-x customize-variable RET eshell-directory-name RET
```

OR

```
(setq eshell-directory-name "~/.emacs.d/eshell")
```

Comment: Sorry, still fails in the same way.   When I try to `M-x customize-variable` I get `[No match]` at the prompt.   I'm trying this on my (Mac GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)) I've also noticed that if I delete ~/.eshell and then symlink it to where I want, I get the same problem even with the variable declaration commented out.  I'm going to try this on my Linux box when I get home to make sure it is not some weird Mac thing.