# What does the f in setf stand for?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

LISP has the `setf` function to assign a value to a variable. Now I have been wondering about the function's name: The `set` part is obvious, but what does the `f` suffix stand for?

Comment: +1 This is an interesting question.  It's not necessarily a programming question, per se, (since it's not about how to **use** setf), but it's not one with an obvious answer, and understanding naming conventions and history can often help a programmer's mental model of the language.  (Incidentally, the `q` in `setq` is easier.   In older Lisps where using a symbol's `symbol-value` was more common, it was nice to abbreviate `(set 'foo …)` as `(setq foo …)` (so the q is for `quote`).)

Comment: Thanks for this nice comment :-)). To me as a LISP beginner some names are hard to grasp, another example is `evenp` and `oddp`: I just wonder what the `p` stands for, and it definitely helps memorizing functions if you really understand their names (and hence their meaning).

Comment: P stands for "predicate"

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.cliki.net/Naming+conventions, but note that it's got "generalized field for f in setf"

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for pointing this out :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The actual meaning of F is often forgotten. According to some sources, f suffix could stand for:

- Field (see for example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/869693/1333873))
- Form (as seen in various teaching materials and manuals)

However, according to Gabriel and Steele's [The Evolution of Lisp](http://www.dreamsongs.com/NewFiles/HOPL2-Uncut.pdf), SETF comes from Peter Deutsch's [A Lisp Machine with Very Compact Programs](https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/interlisp-d/Deutsch-3IJCAI.pdf) (published in 1973) and F stands for **function**.

In this paper, Peter Deutsch wrote:

> The SET function is extended so that so that if the first argument is a list `(fn argl ... argn)` rather than a variable, the function fn is called in "store" mode with arguments `argl ... argn` and newvalue (the second argument of SET). SETQ is also extended in the obvious way, but is not particularly useful. A more useful function is `(SETFQ (fn argl ... argn) newvalue)` which **quotes** the **function** name and evaluates everything else. This allows RPLACA, for example, to be defined as `(LAMBDA (X Y) (SETFQ (CAR X) Y))`.

(emphasis mine)

Gabriel and Steele explain how this became SETF:

> This name was abbreviated to SETF in Lisp-Machine Lisp.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, now I know what terms to watch out for :-)!

Comment: @GoloRoden There are 2 conflicting answers, how do you know this one is correct?

Comment: I can't *know* that it's correct, but I googled for both terms and found another (quite upvoted) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/869693/1333873) that suggest that it's `field`, not `form`. Apart from that, this answer is more helpful as it also points out what the `q` stands for.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Now other people looking at this question can also know how.

Comment: I corrected the answer using reputable sources. F stands for function, not form or field.