# What do common lisp function/special form/macro/etc. names mean and where can I find this information?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

When I was learning HTML it was very helpful for me to know that `ol` means `ordered list`, `tr` is `table row`, etc. Some of the lisp primitives/forms are easy: `funcall` should be `function call`, `defmacro` - `define macro`. Some are in the middle - `incf` is... `increment... f???` But because common lisp is so old, this primitives/special forms/etc... don't seem to ring a bell. **Can you guys, help me with figuring them out?** And even more importantly: **Where can I find an authoritative resource on learning the meaning/history behind each and every one of them?** (I will accept an answer based on this second question)

The documentation doesn't help me too:

```
* (describe #'let)

#<CLOSURE (:SPECIAL LET) {10013DC6AB}>
  [compiled closure]

Lambda-list: (&REST ARGS)
Derived type: (FUNCTION (&REST T) NIL)
Documentation:
  T
Source file: SYS:SRC;COMPILER;INFO-FUNCTIONS.LISP

* (documentation 'let 'function)

"LET ({(var [value]) | var}*) declaration* form*

During evaluation of the FORMS, bind the VARS to the result of evaluating the
VALUE forms. The variables are bound in parallel after all of the VALUES forms
have been evaluated."

* (inspect 'let)

The object is a SYMBOL.
0. Name: "LET"
1. Package: #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP">
2. Value: "unbound"
3. Function: #<CLOSURE (:SPECIAL LET) {10013DC6AB}>
4. Plist: (SB-WALKER::WALKER-TEMPLATE SB-WALKER::WALK-LET)
```

What do the following lisp primitives/special forms/special operators/functions mean?

- let, flet
- progn
- car
- cdr
- acc
- setq, setf
- incf

(write more in the comments so we can make a good list!)

Answer (score 8):

- `let`: **LET** variable-name be bound to a certain value
- `flet`: **LET** **F**unction-name be bound to a certain function
- `progn`: execute a **PROG**ram sequence and return the **N**th value (the last value)
- `car`: **C**ontents of the **A**ddress **R**egister (historic)
- `cdr`: **C**ontents of the **D**ecrement **R**egister (historic)
- `acc`: **ACC**umulator
- `setq`: **SET** **Q**uote, a variant of the `set` function, where in `setq` the user doesn't quote the variable
- `setf`: **SET** **F**unction quoted, shorter name of the original name `setfq`. Here the function/place is not evaluated.
- `incf`: **INC**rement **F**unction quoted, similar to `setf`. Increments a place.

Other conventions:

- Macros / Special Forms who change a place should have an `f` at the end: `setf`, `psetf`, `incf`, `decf`, ...
- Macros who are **DEF**ining something should have `def` or `define` in front: `defun`, `defmethod`, `defclass`, `define-method-combination`...
- Functions who are destructive should have an `n` in front, for **N**on-consing: `nreverse`, ...
- **P**redicates have a `p` or `-p` at the end: `adjustable-array-p`, `alpha-char-p`,...
- special variables have `*` at the front and back: `*standard-output*`, ...

There are other [naming conventions](http://www.cliki.net/Naming+conventions).

Answer (score 4):

- `let`: Well, that's a normal word, and is used like in maths ("let x = 3 in ...").
- `flet`: I'd guess "function `let`", because that's what it does.
- `progn`: This is probably related also to `prog1` and `prog2`. I read is as "**prog**ram whose **n**th form dictates the result value". The program has n forms, so it's the last one that forms the result value of the `progn` form.
- `car` and `cdr`: "Contents address register" resp. "Contents decrement register". This is related [to the IBM 704 which Lisp was originally implemented for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR#Etymology).
- `setq`: "set quote", originally an abbreviation for `(set (quote *abc*) value)`.
- `setf`: "set field", came up when lexical variables appeared. [This is a good read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/869693/1116364) on the `set` functions.

> Where can I find an authoritative resource on learning the meaning/history behind each and every one of them?

The [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/common-lisp.html) is a good place to start, and ultimately the ANSI standard. Though "Common Lisp The Language" could also shine some light on the history of some names.

(Oh, and you got `defmacro` wrong, that's ["Definition for Mac, Read Only.](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html)" ;) )

Comment: Thanks! Of course I know the HyperSpec and Common Lisp The Language, but they don't seem to shed light on the history/meaning behind the operators :) I just checked about the official ANSI standard here: http://www.techstreet.com/standards/incits-226-1994-r1999?product_id=56214 and here http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS+226-1994%5BS2008%5D it is both 60$ :(

Comment: [The almost ANSI CL Standard](http://lispm.de/docs/Publications/Lisp%20Language%20Manuals/1994%20ANSI%20Common%20Lisp.pdf)

Comment: @tsikov The hyperspec contains, within epsilon, the same text as the actual spec, so unless you want paper or an equivalent it's fine (and even if you do there are similarly substantively-identical pdfs around as Rainer has mentioned).  To answer your question: I'm not aware of a definitive source and suspect there is none outside, perhaps, of the memories of some lisp hackers who were there and, perhaps, mailing-list archives.

Comment: Thanks, tfb. In that case, which answer should I accept? :)